# white flash on dark mode on refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

the problem is when the dark mode is enabled, and the page is reloaded for some reason, there's a flicker of white background all over the page before it turns to be dark. It stays a fraction of a second. It just doesn't look professional.
i Know there is already a similar answer i tried, but that one doesn't resolve my problem.

As you can see in the gif [flicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNRSt.gif)

HTML

```
 <header class="header" id="header">
            <nav class="nav container">
                <a href="#home" class="nav__logo smooth">
                    <svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 106.08 30" style="enable-background:new 0 0 106.08 30;" xml:space="preserve">
                        <g id="logo_x5F_brand">
                            <g>
                                <g>
                                    <polygon class="st0" points="34.39,7.99 34.39,22.01 33.05,22.78 30.35,24.34 29,25.12 27.65,25.9 26.31,26.68 24.96,27.45 
                                    23.61,28.23 22.26,29.01 20.91,28.23 19.56,27.45 18.22,26.68 16.87,25.9 15.52,25.12 14.17,24.34 11.48,22.78 10.13,22.01 
                                    10.13,7.99 11.48,7.22 12.82,6.44 14.17,5.66 15.52,4.88 16.87,4.1 18.22,3.32 20.91,1.77 22.26,0.99 23.61,1.77 26.31,3.32 
                                    27.65,4.1 29,4.88 30.35,5.66 31.7,6.44 33.05,7.22           " />
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <g>
                                <g>
                                    <path class="st1" d="M22.3,10.7c-0.34,0.22-0.66,0.44-1,0.66c0.84,0.56,1.69,1.12,2.54,1.68c2.26,1.5,4.52,3,6.78,4.5
                                    c1.02,0.68,0.89,1.89-0.26,2.45c-0.17-0.37-0.55-0.63-0.94-0.89c-4.51-2.99-9.01-5.97-13.51-8.96c-0.59-0.39-0.59-0.85,0.01-1.25
                                    c1.92-1.27,3.84-2.55,5.76-3.82c0.2-0.13,0.37-0.27,0.6-0.44c0.82,0.56,1.58,1.08,2.36,1.6c2.11,1.4,4.22,2.8,6.33,4.2
                                    c0.53,0.35,0.53,0.72,0.01,1.07c-0.99,0.65-1.98,1.31-2.96,1.97c-0.5,0.33-1.07,0.33-1.57,0C25.06,12.53,23.68,11.62,22.3,10.7z
                                    M19.56,10.17c0.91-0.61,1.82-1.22,2.75-1.84c1.64,1.09,3.28,2.18,4.87,3.24c0.34-0.22,0.66-0.43,0.97-0.63
                                    c-1.95-1.29-3.92-2.59-5.86-3.88c-1.23,0.81-2.48,1.63-3.71,2.45C18.88,9.72,19.2,9.93,19.56,10.17z" />
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <path class="st2" d="M27.77,14.46l3.38-2.25v0c0,0.28-0.14,0.54-0.37,0.69l-2.54,1.72v0.01l2.53,1.71
                                    c0.23,0.16,0.37,0.41,0.37,0.69l0,0l-3.36-2.24V14.46z" />
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <path class="st1" d="M22.41,19.25c0.34-0.23,0.66-0.44,0.99-0.66c-0.85-0.55-1.7-1.1-2.55-1.66c-2.27-1.48-4.55-2.96-6.81-4.45
                                    c-1.03-0.67-0.91-1.89,0.24-2.45c0.17,0.37,0.55,0.63,0.95,0.88c4.53,2.95,9.05,5.91,13.58,8.86c0.6,0.39,0.6,0.85,0,1.25
                                    c-1.91,1.29-3.83,2.58-5.74,3.87c-0.19,0.13-0.37,0.28-0.59,0.44c-0.82-0.55-1.59-1.07-2.37-1.58c-2.12-1.39-4.24-2.77-6.36-4.16
                                    c-0.53-0.35-0.53-0.72-0.01-1.07c0.98-0.66,1.97-1.32,2.95-1.99c0.5-0.34,1.06-0.34,1.57-0.01
                                    C19.63,17.43,21.02,18.34,22.41,19.25z M25.16,19.76c-0.9,0.61-1.81,1.23-2.74,1.86c-1.65-1.08-3.29-2.16-4.89-3.21
                                    c-0.34,0.22-0.66,0.44-0.96,0.64c1.96,1.28,3.94,2.57,5.89,3.84c1.23-0.82,2.46-1.65,3.69-2.47
                                    C25.83,20.2,25.51,19.99,25.16,19.76z" />
                                </g>
                                <g>
                                    <path class="st2" d="M16.92,15.53l-3.36,2.27l0,0c0-0.28,0.13-0.54,0.36-0.69l2.53-1.74l0-0.01l-2.54-1.7
                                    c-0.23-0.15-0.37-0.41-0.37-0.69v0l3.38,2.21L16.92,15.53z" />
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                        <g id="name_x5F_brand">
                            <path class="st1" d="M40.64,18.9c0.66,0.41,1.62,0.74,2.63,0.74c1.5,0,2.38-0.79,2.38-1.94c0-1.06-0.61-1.67-2.14-2.26
                            c-1.86-0.66-3.01-1.62-3.01-3.22c0-1.77,1.47-3.09,3.68-3.09c1.17,0,2.01,0.27,2.52,0.56l-0.41,1.2c-0.37-0.2-1.13-0.54-2.16-0.54
                            c-1.55,0-2.14,0.93-2.14,1.71c0,1.06,0.69,1.59,2.26,2.19c1.93,0.74,2.9,1.67,2.9,3.34c0,1.76-1.3,3.28-3.98,3.28
                            c-1.1,0-2.3-0.32-2.9-0.73L40.64,18.9z" />
                            <path class="st1" d="M50.64,9.31v11.38h-1.47V9.31H50.64z" />
                            <path class="st1" d="M62.8,15.69c-0.08-1.59-0.19-3.5-0.17-4.91h-0.05c-0.39,1.33-0.86,2.75-1.44,4.32l-2.01,5.52h-1.11l-1.84-5.42
                            c-0.54-1.6-1-3.07-1.32-4.42h-0.03c-0.03,1.42-0.12,3.33-0.22,5.03l-0.3,4.88h-1.4L53.7,9.31h1.87l1.94,5.5
                            c0.47,1.4,0.86,2.65,1.15,3.83h0.05c0.29-1.15,0.69-2.4,1.2-3.83l2.03-5.5h1.87l0.71,11.38h-1.44L62.8,15.69z" />
                            <path class="st1" d="M76.52,14.88c0,3.92-2.38,5.99-5.28,5.99c-3.01,0-5.12-2.33-5.12-5.77c0-3.61,2.25-5.98,5.28-5.98
                            C74.51,9.12,76.52,11.5,76.52,14.88z M67.69,15.07c0,2.43,1.32,4.61,3.63,4.61c2.33,0,3.65-2.14,3.65-4.73
                            c0-2.26-1.18-4.63-3.63-4.63C68.9,10.32,67.69,12.57,67.69,15.07z" />
                            <path class="st1" d="M78.43,20.69V9.31h1.6l3.65,5.76c0.84,1.33,1.5,2.53,2.04,3.7l0.03-0.02c-0.14-1.52-0.17-2.9-0.17-4.68V9.31
                            h1.38v11.38h-1.49l-3.61-5.77c-0.79-1.27-1.55-2.57-2.13-3.8l-0.05,0.02c0.08,1.43,0.12,2.8,0.12,4.69v4.86H78.43z" />
                            <path class="st1" d="M95.44,15.35h-4.42v4.1h4.93v1.23h-6.4V9.31h6.15v1.23h-4.68v3.6h4.42V15.35z" />
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
                    <ul class="nav__list grid">
                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#home" class="nav__link  smooth">
                                <i class="uil uil-estate nav__icon"></i>Home
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#about" class="nav__link smooth">
                                <i class="uil uil-user nav__icon"></i>About
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#qualification" class="nav__link smooth">
                                <i class="uil uil-briefcase-alt nav__icon"></i>Qualification
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#portfolio" class="nav__link smooth">
                                <i class="uil uil-scenery nav__icon"></i>Portfolio
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#contact" class="nav__link smooth">
                                <i class="uil uil-message nav__icon"></i>Contact
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <i class="uil uil-angle-down icon__menu nav__close" id="nav-close"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="nav__btns">
                    <!-- Theme change button-->
                    <i class="uil uil-moon change-theme" id="theme-button"></i>

                    <div class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle">
                        <i class="uil uil-angle-up icon__menu hover"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

CSS Light

```
/*=============== BASE ===============*/

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--body-color);
    font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
    font-family: var(--body-font);
    color: var(--text-color);
    margin: 0 0 var(--header-height) 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
    color: var(--title-color);
    font-weight: var(--font-semi-bold);
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

CSS dark

```
/*========== Variables Dark theme ==========*/

body.dark-theme {
    --title-color: hsl(var(--hue), 12%, 95%);
    --text-color: hsl(var(--hue), 12%, 75%);
    --body-color: hsl(var(--hue), 40%, 8%);
    --container-color: hsl(var(--hue), 24%, 12%);
}


/*========== Button Dark/Light ==========*/

.nav__btns {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.change-theme {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    color: var(--title-color);
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: var(--mb-2);
}

.change-theme:hover {
    color: var(--first-color);
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
/*==================== DARK LIGHT THEME ====================*/
const themeButton = document.getElementById('theme-button')
const darkTheme = 'dark-theme'
const iconTheme = 'uil-sun'

const selectedTheme = localStorage.getItem('selected-theme')
const selectedIcon = localStorage.getItem('selected-icon')

const getCurrentTheme = () => document.body.classList.contains(darkTheme) ? 'dark' : 'light'
const getCurrentIcon = () => themeButton.classList.contains(iconTheme) ? 'uil-moon' : 'uil-sun'

if (selectedTheme) {
    document.body.classList[selectedTheme === 'dark' ? 'add' : 'remove'](darkTheme)
    themeButton.classList[selectedIcon === 'uil-moon' ? 'add' : 'remove'](iconTheme)
}

themeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle(darkTheme)
    themeButton.classList.toggle(iconTheme)
    localStorage.setItem('selected-theme', getCurrentTheme())
    localStorage.setItem('selected-icon', getCurrentIcon())
})
```

Comment: This is called a FOUC - flash of unstyled content.

Comment: The browser needs time to render your styles. It is not instantaneous to render styles, there isn't a way to fix it except better browser.

Comment: The issue is that the page renders light, *then* your js kicks in to change it to dark.   It could be that your js is too far down the page or if you have it in an onready/jquery doc.ready.  Try moving the code that sets the body class to the top of `<body>` (so body does exist when it runs)

Comment: sorry i didn’t show where is my javascript, it's in the head tag at the beginning as the follows 
( <script src="./dist/js/app.js" defer></script>)

Comment: `defer` is the same (more or less) as putting the script in the page directly after `</body>` (ie at the end of the document).  Try this:  move the `<script>` tag inside `<body>` (first line) and remove the `defer` part.  (you might need to comment out the themeButton code, but at least confirm/test if that helps with the FOUC as it will run before any other content is rendered and add the class to the body, so when the rest of the content is rendered, it will already have the correct style.

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you i tried as you said and now it doesn’t flicker anymore

Comment: *i Know there is already a similar answer i tried, but that one doesn't resolve my problem.* - closing without resolving the problem doesn't help OP.  And the linked answer would not be able to apply a class to body as requested.

Comment: @freedomn-m i didn’t closed the question but somehow it linked with a similar answer and it closed automatically why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a common issue called FOUC - flash of unstyled content.

Caused by `<script src=... defer></script>`

Or, in other cases, by running the dark mode script inside `doc.ready`

What happens is that your page renders (with light style) and then, when the page has finished rendering, the `defer` script runs (just before `DOMContentLoaded`).

As the page has already been rendered, you see it with the *light* styles, until the js has a chance to add your `dark-theme` to the `body` tag.

This will have nothing to do with how long it takes to "parse"/"apply" the css, given the assumption that these too are in the `<head>` then they will be applied before content is rendered; if this takes a long time then it will still be before the rest of the HTML is rendered (giving a blank page for that duration).

The solution is to run the js as soon as possible within the html document.  eg:

```
<head>
   ... css and other js scripts
</head>
<body>
   <script>
const selectedTheme = localStorage.getItem('selected-theme')
document.body.classList[selectedTheme === 'dark' ? 'add' : 'remove'](darkTheme)
   </script>
   ... rest of body
```

the script will run at the time it appears in the render process - before the unstyled content is rendered.  So you never see the unstyled content.

Care needs to be taken, for example OPs code also sets a class and a click event on a button; that button won't exist yet.