# How to make Jquery Darkmode load directly on the beginning?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, local-storage

So I have set up a theme switcher on my site, which stores preference in localStorage and everything works fine. Except that my code is loaded after document.ready, and checks for condition / status of theme. I also tried removing document.ready, because obviously that would remove any finishing of loading the site, but that doesn't work, and the function starts direct on load and obviously can't change any CSS, because there isn't any. For now, I am using a preloader, which is working fine, but it would be awesome if it could work without it. I have also placed the code at the beginning of the body tag, so it should execute really early. In the following, I will show you my code and a screenshot of my console, where you can see when the code gets executed. For your knowledge, I am on Shopify, if that does anything.

Any help for making my theme / code switch faster, is very much appreciated.

My Console:
[console img...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFXo1.png)

My Code (I am sorry for the formatting, I made if farly quickly in the Shopify admin, so no "Prettier" and also no "IntelliSense" :) )

```js
// Darkmode @legoon @raffaelbaer



let ALLDARKMODE = '#over-header-info-bar-legoon, #StickyBar, .full-width--return-link,' +
  '.cart__subtotal, .transcy-money, .site-footer__newsletter-input, #product-title__cart-page-legoon, .cart-table,' +
  '.responsive-table__row, label, .gridforsubcategories_item-grid, .linkitem_hassubcategoriesinner, .sticky--active, .sticky--open,' +
  '.icon-hamburger, .icon-close, .drawer__inner, #einloggendrawerlink, .drawer__nav-link--top-level, .einloggensvgmobile, .drawer__search,' +
  '.drawer__search-input, #legooninstagrammobile, #instagramiconheadermobile, .svgdarkmode, .drawer__nav-item, .drawerforsocialicons, #footerlegoonlink,' +
  '.content-block, .icon-arrow-down, .product-card__name, .product-card__info, .country-selector, .site-header__search-input, .menu-sub-custom1, .menu-sub-custom2,' +
  '.labelcustomnav1, .labelcustomnav2, .labelcustomnav3, .labelcustomnav4, .menu-sub-custom3, .menu-sub-custom4, .nav-bar, h1, h2, #footer-down_copyright, h3, h4, h5,' +
  'h6, body, a, input, textarea, select, .link-item>a , #instagramiconheader, .site-footer, .site-footer__copyright, .darkmodeswitch, p, .site-footer__newsletter-label>p,' +
  'button, #icon-wunschliste, .page-container, .labelcustomnav1>p, .labelcustomnav2>p, .labelcustomnav3>p, .labelcustomnav4>p, .site-header, .legoonlogotop, .iconuserhead, .icon-cart,' +
  '.notification--success, .notification--promo, .notification__message>span, .wg-drop.country-selector, .hr-empfy_cart-page';


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.darkmodeswitch').click(function() {

    /*main toggle dark mode*/
    $(ALLDARKMODE).toggleClass("dark");

    /*change darkmode image on mobile drawer and desktop accordingly to current mode | theme (light or dark)*/

    if ($(".darkmodeswitch").hasClass("dark")) {

      document.getElementById('svgdarkmode').src = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0571/7137/8349/files/sun.svg?v=1650307091";
      document.getElementById('svgdarkmodemobile').src = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0571/7137/8349/files/sun.svg?v=1650307091";
      localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");

    } else {

      document.getElementById('svgdarkmode').src = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0571/7137/8349/files/moon.svg?v=1650306791";
      document.getElementById('svgdarkmodemobile').src = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0571/7137/8349/files/moon.svg?v=1650306791";
      localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");

    };
  });

  // Am Anfang

  if (localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark") {
    console.log("Darkmode status = true");
    $(ALLDARKMODE).addClass("dark");
  } else {
    console.log("Darkmode status = false");
    $(ALLDARKMODE).removeClass("dark");
  }
  
  $('.darkmodeswitch').click();
});
```

Comment: *no "Prettier"* - but there *is* one in Stack Overflow snippet editor :)

Comment: Related questions (not necessarily exact duplicates, but close):  [flash on dark mode on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71799083/2181514) / [dark mode flicker on reload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63033412/2181514)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a dark mode switch, simply toggle a CSS class on the HTML element (`document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark');`), and use that as a contextual selector for changes on your elements. Use CSS custom properties for the changes.

Here's an example of the approach. Please note that `localStorage` is unavailable in StackOverflow snippets due to security reasons, so I left that part out (you've got that working already anyway).

```js
function toggleDarkMode() {
  document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark');
}
```

```css
:root {
  --body-bg-color: #fff;
  --btn-bg-color: #f0f0f0;
  --btn-fg-color: #333;
}

:root.dark {
  --body-bg-color: #666;
  --btn-bg-color: #333;
  --btn-fg-color: #f0f0f0;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--body-bg-color);
}

button {
  background-color: var(--btn-bg-color);
  border: 1px solid #888;
  color: var(--btn-fg-color);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="toggle" onclick="toggleDarkMode()">Dark Mode Button</button>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for your answer, but that wasn't quite what I was looking for... So the Darkmode is already working perfect. It's just about the loading speed it takes to excecute... For what I saw from your code working with root, it will let to the same output I guess, I just don't have to set all colors manually, but just with two or maybe three root variables. But does using variables make the loading faster? Also I saw your'e from germany, so we can talk in German if you want :).

Comment: wait a sec, I have tried it out and it works!! But why is this

Comment: I have set up everything now and it works perfect!! Thanks you so much... :)