# Dark theme loads in after 1-2 seconds

Tags: javascript, wordpress, asynchronous, toggle, darkmode

I want to let the user switch between light and dark mode. The switch is working and also the 2 themes work. But when I have dark mode enabled and I refresh te page, the light theme loads in for about 1/2 seconds and after that it switches to dark mode. All my colors are defined with :root {...} & .dark-theme{...} in an sass file.

The dark modes load in with localstorage which I execute when the page is loaded. I tried an async function but that didn't work. Altough I don't know if I did it right.

```
function checkTheme() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const userPreference = localStorage.getItem('theme');

        if (userPreference === "dark") {
            // Als de gebruiker het donkere thema verkiest, voeg de donkere thema-klasse toe aan de body
            document.body.classList.add("dark-theme");

            // Zet de checkbox op "Dark Mode"
            document.getElementById("themeToggle").checked = true;
        }

        resolve();
    });

}
```

this is my function where I execute the check on which theme needs to be selected.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var reloading = sessionStorage.getItem("reloading");
    if (reloading) {
        sessionStorage.removeItem("reloading");
        openNextServiceTab(2);
    }

    Promise.all([
        checkTheme(),
        loadFilters(), 
        fillDropdown(), 
        initMap(),
    ]);
   
    if (window.location.pathname == '/login') {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

This is the function where the function gets executed.

```
:root {
    --primary-color: #0B1505;
    --secondary-color: #FFFFFF;
    --background-gray : rgb(11,21,5);
    --linearbackground-gray : linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(11,21,5,1) 0%, rgba(84,84,84,1) 100%);
    --background-green :rgb(117,247,75);
    --linearbackground-green: linear-gradient(100deg, rgba(117,247,75,1) 0%, rgba(84,84,84,1) 100%);
    --background-gray-green : rgb(11,21,5);
    --linearbackground-gray-green: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(11,21,5,1) 0%, rgba(84,84,84,1) 100%);
    --border: 1px solid #0B1505;
    --gray : #726f6f;
    --green: #75F74B;
    --input-gray: #2E332B;
    --thead: #3C9673;
    --input-border : transparent;
}
.dark-theme {
    --primary-color: #FFFFFF;
    --secondary-color: #0B1505;
    --background-gray : rgba(11,21,5, 0);
    --linearbackground-gray : rgba(11,21,5, 0);
    --border: 1px solid #3C9673;
    --gray : #3C9673;
    --background-green : #3C9673;
    --linearbackground-green: #3C9673;
    --background-gray-green : #3C9673;
    --linearbackground-gray-green: #3C9673;
    --green: #3C9673;
    --input-gray: #FFFFFF;
    --input-border : 1px solid #3C9673;
    --thead: #f1f1f1;
}
```

This is where my colors are getting defined.

Comment: "*The dark modes load in with localstorage which I execute when the page is loaded* - you mean: which you execute *after* the page has loaded.   Your page loads, parses any js etc, *then* loads your css (which it still needs to parse).  This is called "FOUC".  The client-side solution is to not wait for the page to load.  The server-side solution is to store the value server-side and render with dark mode already active.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [white flash on dark mode on refreshing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71799083/white-flash-on-dark-mode-on-refreshing-page)

Comment: The brief explanation for the issue is that the initial page load defaults to the light theme before the JavaScript executes and switches to the dark theme. To address this, consider placing the theme-switching script in the head of your document to expedite its execution and minimize the flicker during page reload.

Comment: @freedomn-m 's solution works! I've put the theme switching script in the body tag!